# How to get All Users in User Profile Services Sharepoint 2013 Using CSOM

Tags: 2013, powershell, csom, user-profile-service

I need some function like bellow on CSOM.
could you help me ?

---

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) { 
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" 
} 

$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("<<WebApplicationSiteUrl>>");  
$ServiceContext = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext]::GetContext($site);  

$ProfileManager = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($ServiceContext)    
$AllProfiles = $ProfileManager.GetEnumerator()  

foreach($profile in $AllProfiles)  
{  
    $DisplayName = $profile.DisplayName  
    $AccountName = $profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::AccountName].Value  
    write-host "Profile for account ", $AccountName
}  
write-host "Finished." 
$site.Dispose()
```

Comment: Here is another way to do the same : https://sharepointumar.wordpress.com/2017/07/16/list-all-users-in-user-profile-service-application-db-in-sharepoint/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an working example with PeopleManager but you can loop for web.Siteusers . Also [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163182.aspx) msdn page will help you.

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("<Your SP Site>"))
        {
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            clientContext.Load(web);
            clientContext.Load(web.SiteUsers);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            UserCollection users = web.SiteUsers;
            PeopleManager peopleManager = new PeopleManager(clientContext);

            foreach (User user in users)
            {
                PersonProperties personProperties = peopleManager.GetPropertiesFor(user.LoginName);
                clientContext.Load(personProperties, p => p.AccountName, p => p.DisplayName, p => p.UserProfileProperties);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                Console.WriteLine(personProperties.DisplayName);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```